Drug dosage determination using dynamical systems
I am a Mathematical Biology student, and recently I have read about various approaches, such as Ordinary Differential Equations (ODEs), used to determine the exact drug dosage and treatment sessions required to achieve a desired response. I'm wondering do PK/PD models too involve deep analysis of equilibrium points and their stability? Can these methods account for biochemical or biological elements, such as immune or specific tissue cells?
For example, I have come across three articles on this topic:
1.Chemotherapy model for bladder cancer:
https://www.frontiersin.org/journals/oncology/articles/10.3389/fonc.2024.1352065/full
2.Optimal control of a mathematical model for cancer chemotherapy:
https://www.aimspress.com/article/10.3934/mbe.20160403.
3.Physiologically based modelling of the antiplatelet effect of aspirin
https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0268905
Would be grateful for guidance.

These are rather complicated models, if you have not already done so you could start by looking at texts such as N. Britton, 'Essential Mathematical Biology', which has a chapter on tumour modelling, S. Strogatz, 'Non-linear Dynamics & Chaos',  and perhaps D. Acheson 'from Calculus to Chaos'.
